# Hubot script only works in Slack when I directly message the robot

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript, hubot, slack

Right now, my Hubot robot is techinically working. If I direct message this message to the robot in Slack:

```
qbot !npm bower
```

It will reply with this link:

```
https://www.npmjs.com/package/bower
```

It also works if I just do:

```
!npm bower
```

However, if I say either of those messages in the general channel, the robot doesn't do anything. Any help would be appreciated! Here is the script if it helps at all:

```
# Description:
#   Get a link to an npm module
#
# Dependencies:
#   request
#
# Configuration:
#   None
#
# Commands:
#   qbot !npm <module>

request = require "request"

module.exports = (robot) ->
  robot.hear /\!npm (.*)/i, (res) ->
    module = res.match[1]
    query = "https://www.npmjs.com/package/#{module}"

    request query, (error, response, body) ->
      unless error or response.statusCode is 404
        res.send query
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a long time since I've done it myself, but I believe you want to `/invite` your hubot by name from the channel you want to use it in.  See the docs here: https://github.com/slackhq/hubot-slack#configuration